# Class cast exception with generics in Jackson module kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, jackson, project-reactor

I have a **generic** Redis service that basically helps to get data from Redis.
It uses a generic **jackson-module-kotlin** which deserializes using the reified property.

I am getting the following exception while using the list. Somehow type information is getting erased.

```
org.springframework.core.codec.EncodingException: JSON encoding error: object is not an instance of declaring class; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: object is not an instance of declaring class (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["stationId"])
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:229) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.reactive.sse.controllers.WeatherInfoController#getWeatherInfoData(String) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/get/weather?key=today" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:229) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.lambda$encode$0(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:358) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:886) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$RedisSubscription.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:291) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$SubscriptionCommand.doOnComplete(RedisPublisher.java:773) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:65) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:746) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:681) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:598) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: object is not an instance of declaring class (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["stationId"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:390) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:349) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:316) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:778) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContentsUsing(CollectionSerializer.java:171) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:116) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._serialize(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:480) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:400) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1510) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1006) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:222) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.lambda$encode$0(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsingWhen$UsingWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxUsingWhen.java:358) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:100) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$ImmediateSubscriber.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:886) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$RedisSubscription.onNext(RedisPublisher.java:291) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisPublisher$SubscriptionCommand.doOnComplete(RedisPublisher.java:773) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:65) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:746) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:681) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:598) ~[lettuce-core-6.1.2.RELEASE.jar:6.1.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.65.Final.jar:4.1.65.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:770) ~[jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:2.12.3]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

**Generic ObjectMapper Code**

```kotlin
package com.reactive.sse.common

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component


@Component
final class ObjectMapper {
    val jacksonObjectMapper: ObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(JavaTimeModule())

    init {
        jacksonObjectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS)
        jacksonObjectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_DECIMAL_FOR_FLOATS)
        jacksonObjectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)
        jacksonObjectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
    }

    fun serialize(obj: Any): String {
        return jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj)
    }


    inline fun <reified T> deserialize(obj: String): T {
        return jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(obj, object : TypeReference<T>() {}) as T
    }

}
```

**Generic Redis Service**

```kotlin
package com.reactive.sse.services

import com.reactive.sse.common.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.ReactiveRedisTemplate
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono


@Service
final class RedisService(
    val redisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, String>,
    val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) {
    inline fun <reified T : Any> put(key: String, value: T): Mono<Boolean> {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, objectMapper.serialize(value))
    }

    inline fun <reified T> get(key: String): Mono<T> {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key).map { data ->
            // Create a ArrayList of LinkedHashMap instead of List of WeatherInfoEvent
            val value = objectMapper.deserialize<T>(data)
            value
        }
    }


    inline fun <reified T : Any> getMany(keys: List<String>): Flux<T> {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().multiGet(keys)
            .flatMapMany { data: List<String> -> Flux.fromIterable(data) }
            .filter { data: String -> data.isNotEmpty() }
            .flatMapIterable { data: String ->
                val value = objectMapper.deserialize<Iterable<T>>(data)
                value
            }
    }

    fun delete(key: String): Mono<Boolean> {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().delete(key)
    }
}
```

#### Usage of generic Redis service

```kotlin
 fun getWeatherDataFromRedis(key: String): Mono<List<WeatherInfoEvent>> {
        val data =  redisService.get<List<WeatherInfoEvent>>(key)
        return data
    }
```

I am setting data to redis as follows using its sli

```sh
SET yesterday "[{\"stationId\":145,\"temperature\":256}]"
```

But when I do this, type information is not lost

```kotlin
class GenericTest {
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()

    inline fun <reified T> deserialize(str: String): T {
            val value = objectMapper.deserialize<T>(str)
            return value
    }
}

fun main() {
    val test = GenericTest()
    val listStr = "[{\"stationId\":145,\"temperature\":256}]"
    val weatherInfoList = test.deserialize<List<WeatherInfoEvent>>(listStr)
    println(weatherInfoList is List<WeatherInfoEvent>)


    val str = "{\"stationId\":145,\"temperature\":256}"
    val weatherInfo = test.deserialize<WeatherInfoEvent>(str)
    println(weatherInfo is WeatherInfoEvent)
}
```

Github code https://github.com/Zaky7/Generic-Object-Mapper

### **Update**

I have fixed the problem by making these changes, but I feel like this is bit of a hack and could be non performant. I have also update this in github repo.

For list, I am using this function

```kotlin
  inline fun <reified T : Any> getList(key: String): Mono<List<T>> {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key).map { data ->
            val type = objectMapper.jacksonObjectMapper.constructType(T::class.java)
            val listType = objectMapper.jacksonObjectMapper.typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List::class.java, type)
            val listData = objectMapper.deserialize(data, listType)

            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            listData as List<T>
        }
    }
```

For single object I am using the function

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T: Any> get(key: String): Mono<T> {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key).map { data ->
            val value = objectMapper.jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(data, T::class.java)
            value
        }
    }
```

For Iterable i am using this

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> getMany(keys: List<String>): Flux<T> {
        return redisTemplate.opsForValue().multiGet(keys)
            .flatMapMany { data: List<String> -> Flux.fromIterable(data) }
            .filter { data: String -> data.isNotEmpty() }
            .flatMapIterable { data: String ->
                val type = objectMapper.jacksonObjectMapper.constructType(T::class.java)
                val iterableType = objectMapper.jacksonObjectMapper.typeFactory.constructCollectionType(Collection::class.java, type)
                val iterableData = objectMapper.deserialize(data, iterableType)

                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                iterableData as Iterable<T>
                iterableData
            }
    }
```

```kotlin
 fun deserialize(obj: String, type: JavaType): Any {
        return jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(obj, type)
    }
```

Any feedback for improvement are welcomed.

Comment: This is besides the question, but what's the point of the Generic `ObjectMapper` class if you're using `jackson-module-kotlin`? Jackson's `ObjectMapper` already has similar extensions with the Kotlin module, so why not inject it directly instead?

Comment: OK, I would update my code but that does not answer the question.

Comment: I was able to solve my explicitly passing class
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/476